# What are the qualifications for the Korean E-7 visa?

Tags: visa, working-visas, south-korea

I've a job offer in South Korea and I would like to know if I have the needed qualifications for the E-7 visa.

I have 5 years and 2 months of experience in IT. The company that is going to sponsor my visa is also in the IT field. I completed a 3-year Associate Degree program, but the final exam is still pending. Because of that, I don't have a diploma yet.

Will that affect being granted the E-7 visa?

Comment: In your case, the date of your final exam won't matter. A 3-year associate degree doesn't give you an edge. Your professional experience *should* be enough. But it'll be up to the gremlins in Mok-dong (where the Immigration office is).

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Ministry of Labor](http://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt), the E-7 is granted to:

> Foreigner who want to engage in occupations specially designated by the Ministry of Justice after making an employment contract with a public or private organization in Korea.

Applicants have to satisfy one of the following requirements:

- A Master’s degree or higher in the relevant field
- A Bachelor’s degree and at least one year of work experience in the relevant field
- At least 5 years of work experience in the relevant field

Your background does seem to fit; however, only those who review the application can determine whether the absence of the diploma would be  an issue.